# Test a piece of code in offline and online but count as 2 cases xctests

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

The below code verifies whether the app is not allowed to access camera or not, similarly i have 30 other cases.
I want to test all these by mocking the device to be offline, assume that to be a single function call

```
func makeDeviceOffline(){

   ....
}

func testisCameraDisabled(){

   driver?.openApp()
   dashBoard?.openCameraPage()
   cameraPage?.openCamera()
   XCTAssert(elementFinder?.isPolicyViolationAlertExists("camera"))

}
```

Instead of repeating each and every case in offline mode, is there any better alternative approach

In final reports i need that to be counted as 2 different test cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- You have a test case class `MyTests` that is a kind of `XCTestCase` with some test methods.
- You want to create another test case class `MyOfflineTests` that is identical to `MyTests`, except that `makeDeviceOffline` runs before each test.

Then:

- You can subclass `MyTests` to create `MyOfflineTests` and override `-setUp` to call `makeDeviceOffline()`.

Example:

```
class MyTests: XCTestCase {
  func testIsCameraDisabled() {
    // …
  }
}

class MyOfflineTests: MyTests {
  override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    makeDeviceOffline()
  }

  // All tests of `MyTests` are now run as offline tests.
}
```

NOTE: The inherited tests will be discovered and listed at **runtime.** They won't show up in Xcode's test navigator panel till after you've run the `MyOfflineTests` class's tests at least once. They will show up as properly counted in the overall test-run output.